# Cognito Password Reset does not trigger lambda

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Users are unable to reset passwords. Calling:

```
import Auth from "@aws-amplify/auth";
...
Auth.forgotPassword(username);
```

yields a successful response with the following data:

```
{CodeDeliveryDetails: {…}}
CodeDeliveryDetails:
AttributeName: "email"
DeliveryMedium: "EMAIL"
Destination: "k***@g***.com"
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

My configuration looks as follows:

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    mandatorySignIn: true,
    region: secrets.cognito.region,
    userPoolId: secrets.cognito.poolId,
    userPoolWebClientId: secrets.cognito.webClientId,
    oauth: {
      domain: "auth.domain.com",
    },
  },
});
```

, as per [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/start/q/platform/js#re-use-existing-authentication-resource).

The custom lambda registered in the Cognito UI gets successfully invoked for `CustomMessage_SignUp`, but it does not get invoked for `CustomMessage_ForgotPassword`, even though it should, as per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html).

This flow used to work (lambda was invoked with `CustomMessage_ForgotPassword`), but it suddenly stopped, without any code changes nor configuration changes in the Cognito UI. What could be wrong?

Comment: Does the user has `email_verified` attribute as `true`?

Comment: @UlasKeles No - good find. It works for users with email_verified. I wish this was somehow signalled through an error somewhere in the stack. Instead, this just silently does not trigger the lambda.